# Будут призывать животнЫЕ и растенИЯ или животнЫХ и растенИЙ?

Tags: окончания

Вопрос можно считать уже решённым: в шестую волну мобилизации будут призывать животнЫЕ и растенИЯ!
(Или животнЫХ и растенИЙ?)

Comment: Призывать=призвать. Призвать кого/что (в. п.) Значит "Призывать животных и растения". https://slovarozhegova.ru/word.php?wordid=23763

Comment: Если имеется в виду, что животные и растения будут входить в состав призывной комиссии, то это одно (они будут призывать). Если же имеется в виду, что они будут в качестве призывников, то это уже нечто совсем иное (их будут призывать). А если и с той стороны будут, и с этой, ситуация ещё интереснее получается!

Answer (score 1):

Предложение фантастичное, поэтому смыслов тут можно *понапредставлять* множество.
А управление у глагола ["призвать"](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/182006) (сов.; призывать, несов.) такое:
**4.** *кого (что)*. Потребовать явки на военную службу.

*Будут призывать* (кого? В. п.) *животных и* (что? В. п.) *растения* (в армию пойдут животные и растения).

Начиная с этой осени на службу не будут призывать «свежих» выпускников вузов (Виктор Козлов. До дембеля далеко, до военкомата близко (2001) // «Семья», 14.11.2001).

Если же предположить, что слова "животное" (человек, не придерживающийся общепринятых норм общественного поведения) и "растение" (человек "декоративный", "оранжерейный" или человек глубоко больной, лежачий или умалишенный) имеют переносный смысл, то *будут призывать животных и растений.*

Проще написать так:
будут призываться животные и растения; будут призваны животные и растения.